# Xcode Search Path and Blue Folders

Tags: xcode, build, header, include

I have a simple directory structure that I use to build my projects which is compatible with a simple makefile.

I have a directory called `include/` within my project folder, and this directory contains headers, mostly from the libraries that I link to.

So, in Xcode I'd like to simply include this folder full of includes so that my sources and headers from the Xcode project can find them, so that I can compile. I'm going to worry about compiling these libraries to link to them once I can get my source files compiled.

I have added my include folder so that it shows up as a blue folder in the Xcode project, and it also exists in "real directory" form inside the Xcode project directory in the filesystem. It is called "include".

I have also put `"include/**"` into the Project Search Paths configuration settings under Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths and turned on Always Search User Paths to no avail. The build fails to find my headers.

I really don't want to have a completely different way to organize all my files in order to work with Xcode (there are just too many of them).

Surely somebody here has experience getting an existing project like this to compile in Xcode. Any help is appreciated. Basically, I'm trying to set up a reasonably quick way to get an existing makefile project compiling in Xcode.

Comment: So, your problem is:

Project can't find a resource?

Comment: Yep... It just won't see any headers I try to add.

Comment: Unless I dump them into the root of the directory. Which is definitely the wrong way from an organizational perspective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this steps

1) Don't add your headers at  Project

2) cmd + 1

3) Choose your target

4) In "Build Settings->Header Search Paths" add "$(SRCROOT)/include"

Comment: Well, I did something like this, and it eventually worked. The interface for adding values to Header Search Paths is *super* clunky.